# What is Executed Unit's Count on Developer Console?

Tags: developer-console

[image]

Please let me know if it means record count on each object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Count column in the Executed Units section of the Execution Overview panel when using Log Analysis (with Profiling) does not represent the record count for the object but actually gives you insight to the number of times this "item" was called in the transaction (or log itself).

Both validations seen in your attached image ran 33 times for what appears to be a single DML insert with 33 rows. In this case, the validation ran for each record being saved and committed to the DB.